# Bluemix API to spin up Softlayer compute resources

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now that Softlayer services are integrated with Bluemix, can I use Bluemix APIs to spin up SF compute resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, The SoftLayer and Bluemix API's are independent, you should use the SoftLayer's API for it.

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)